# Syntax error after updating the Server to new version

Tags: node.js, apache, ubuntu, meteor, passenger

Hi Stackoverflow Community :),

we updated the server system to:

Meteor 1.5.2.2

ubuntu Release:        14.04
Server version: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
Phusion Passenger 6.0.2

just with a small update and suddenly we get the issue like attached. can you plz help us if you have any clue what we can do to fix that issue?

we just run an update of the subversions.

[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rdlsd.png)

[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FdmcK.png)

[image3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bc8nb.png)
[image4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/132T9.png)

Comment: Please don't post images of text, copy and paste the text directly (in your case thr errors).

Comment: Please post your code as text, not image.